# "tempdb.mdf" increasing to astronomical sizes (i.e. 800GB) due to SQL query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have been trying to run the following SQL on my SQL Server. However, I keep coming across an error that is the result of the `tempdb.mdf` file increasing to such astronomical sizes that it occupies the entire hard disk (800GB). Is there anyway to resolve this?

The SQL query is as follows:

```
SELECT 
    t1.[mmsi], t1.[tagblock_timestamp], t1.[x] , t1.[y], 
    t1.[sog], t1.[Location Code],
    DATEDIFF(second , MAX (t2.[tagblock_timestamp]),   
    t1.[tagblock_timestamp]) AS LengthOfRecord
INTO 
    [dbo]. [VehProcessed]
FROM 
    [dbo]. [VehMovement] t1 
LEFT JOIN 
    [dbo]. [VehMovement] t2 ON t1. [mmsi] = t2 .[mmsi] 
                            AND t2.[tagblock_timestamp] < t1.[tagblock_timestamp]
GROUP BY 
    t1.[mmsi], t1.[tagblock_timestamp], t1.[x], t1.[y], t1.[sog], t1.[Location Code];
```

Comment: Can you use SQL Server 2012+ (for `LAG` function)? Can you change the query? Can you create index(es)? How many rows are in `VehMovement`?

Comment: I am open to ideas for changing the query and creating indexes. However, I cannot change the version of SQL Server. Will creating indexes work?

Comment: How many records you are dealing with?Size?

Comment: There are 31 million records in [dbo].[VehProcessed] table. The size is around 3 GB.

Comment: Please post an execution plan here. You can anonimyse it with [SQL Sentry Plan Explorer](http://www.sqlsentry.net/plan-explorer/sql-server-query-view.asp) if you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create an index on `(mmsi, tagblock_timestamp DESC)`. This is a must.

The following query is not so efficient as `LAG` function (which is available since SQL Server 2012+), but it should be better than you have.

```
SELECT
    t1.[mmsi]
    ,t1.[tagblock_timestamp]
    ,t1.[x]
    ,t1.[y]
    ,t1.[sog]
    ,t1.[Location Code]
    ,DATEDIFF(second, A.[tagblock_timestamp], t1.[tagblock_timestamp]) AS LengthOfRecord
INTO
    [dbo].[VehProcessed]
FROM
    [dbo].[VehMovement] AS t1
    OUTER APPLY
    (
        SELECT TOP(1) t2.[tagblock_timestamp]
        FROM [dbo].[VehMovement] AS t2
        WHERE 
            t1.[mmsi] = t2.[mmsi]
            AND t2.[tagblock_timestamp] < t1.[tagblock_timestamp]
        ORDER BY t2.[tagblock_timestamp] DESC
    ) AS A
;
```

You want to calculate the difference between consecutive rows. It is very likely that on SQL Server 2008 the best method would be to use a simple cursor.

Comment: The index that you've suggested is for the table alias 'A`, isn't it?

Comment: @BPavanKumar, Index is for table `VehMovement`. It is the only table in the query. "Index for alias" doesn't make sense. Index is a physical object and can be created only for tables (and sometimes views).

Comment: Yeah, I understand - I was referring to the purpose of usage (of this index). I got your point!

Comment: @BPavanKumar, yes, the purpose of this index is to make the subquery `A` as efficient as possible, because it will run for each row of the table (31 million times).

Comment: @VladimirBaranov, looks like you lost the `AND t2.[tagblock_timestamp] < t1.[tagblock_timestamp]` condition for the `apply`.

Comment: I added another condition for the sub-query to work:


`SELECT TOP(1) t2.[tagblock_timestamp]
        FROM [dbo].[VehMovement] AS t2
        WHERE t1.[mmsi] = t2.[mmsi] AND t2.[tagblock_timestamp] < t1.[tagblock_timestamp]
        ORDER BY t2.[tagblock_timestamp] DESC;` The query works super fast. It took less than 1 minute to go through 31 million records.

Comment: @RogerWolf, yes, you are right, I missed it. I'll fix the answer.

Comment: @Cloud, I'm glad it helped you. If you could use `LAG`, the speed would be almost the same as simple `SELECT ... FROM VehMovement`.